# How to outline a histogram with a color and add a bell curve on ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

I have been trying to add a bell curve to my histogram an outline it with a color so that it is more pleasing. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYSL4.jpg)

I have added what  my histogram looks like to give someone an idea on what I am working with, also here is my code thus far, thank you in advance.

```html
ggplot(data = mammal.data.22.select2)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=Time, fill=Species))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("paleturquoise4", "turquoise2"))+
  facet_wrap(~Species, nrow=1)+
  ylab("Observations")+
  xlab("Time of Day")+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

Comment: Have you looked at `stat_function`?

Answer (score 4):

Let's build a histogram with a build-in dataset that seems similar-ish to your data structure.

```r
library(ggplot2)

binwidth <- 0.25

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(fill = Species), 
    binwidth = binwidth, 
    alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

You can use `stat_bin()` + `geom_step()` to give an outline to the histogram, without colouring the edge of every rectangle in the histogram. The only downside is that the first and last bins don't touch the x-axis.

```r
p + stat_bin(
  geom = "step", direction = "mid",
  aes(colour = Species), binwidth = binwidth
)
```

[image]

To overlay a density function with a histogram, you could calculate the relevant parameters yourself and use `stat_function()` with `fun = dnorm` repeatedly. Alternatively, you can use `ggh4x::stat_theodensity()` to achieve a similar thing. Note that whether you use `stat_function()` or `stat_theodensity()`, you should scale the density back to the counts that your histogram uses (or scale histogram to density). In  the example below, we do that by using `after_stat(count * binwidth)`.

```r
p + ggh4x::stat_theodensity(
  aes(colour = Species,
      y = after_stat(count * binwidth))
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

(disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x)